# How can i pass my data in sqlite database to templates? ( to make line chart using highcharts)

Tags: json, django, sqlite, highcharts, django-queryset

i'm developing web application using dJango.

My current situation is as below

1. When users do something, the data is saved into sqlite database
2. I want to pass my data to templates and draw line chart
3. I want X-axle : YYYY-MM-DD / Y-axle : the count of request

But, i have no idea how to make it.

{{ addRequestCnt }} is presented like as below.

"QuerySet [{'doDate':datetime.datetime(2019,4,15,0,0),'requestType__count':11}, {'doDate':datetime.datetime(2019,4,16,0,0),'requestType__Count':7}]>" 
......

Thank you for helpful answer in advance.

My models.py

```
class ActivityLog(models.Model):
    doDate = models.DateTimeField()
    requestType = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

My views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
    addRequestCnt = ActivityLog.objects.filter(requestType='add').values('doDate').annotate(Count('requesetType'))

    context = {
        'addRequestCnt':json.dumps(addRequest, default=str),
    }

    return render(request,'dashboard.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is an example of a blog post model, our database schema](https://github.com/Belonias/personal-site/blob/master/src/posts/models.py)

[Here is how to return the data to the template a list view](https://github.com/Belonias/personal-site/blob/master/src/templates/post_list.html)

[And here is how to return data to the detail view](https://github.com/Belonias/personal-site/blob/master/src/templates/post_detail.html)

What you want on your template based on your model is something like this:

```html
{% block content %}
<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>

<h1>{{ doDate }}</h1>
<h2><small>{{ requestType }}</small></h2>
{% endblock content %}
```

[Here is the official documentation for Django templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/)

Comment: you should look for  a way to handle your json response via ajax  as i have with highchart before though with php and ajax